# How to set Y axis intersect to a specific date on X axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have time series data set that I would like to plot.

X axis data points are of type `Timestamp('2000-01-04 00:00:00')`
Y axis data points are of type `float`

When I do the usual `ax.plot(x, y)` the chart prints fine, but the Y axis crosses the X axis a few pixels off to the left from start of the data on the X axis.
So I tried to set the intersect with various combinations like:

```
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', '2000-01-04'))
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 946944000000000000))
```

but none of them worked.

How can I set the desired X axis intersect if X axis is

```
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-04', 
               ...
               '2021-12-17'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=5535, freq=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, with the following chart:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
...
plt.xticks(rotation="vertical")
plt.plot(df)
```

[image]

You can adjust the w-axis like this:

```py
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.plot(df)
```

[image]